# Set root path to serve index.html on Azure (IIS webserver)

Tags: node.js, azure, iis

I have a fairly standard node app deployed to Azure. By default, for a request of `http:www.example.com/my_path` Azure adds a `web.config` xml file to set up IIS so it will:

a) see if a static file matching `/my_path` exists in the `/public` folder
b) route all other requests to the nodejs app.

That's close to what I want, except that for the root path (`http:www.example.com/`) I want it to just display `public/index.html`, and at the moment it routes the root path to the node app.

I'm unable to get it to do that. Here's the relevant section from my `web.config`:

```xml
<!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
<rule name="StaticContent">
  <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
</rule>

<!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
<rule name="DynamicContent">
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
    <!-- WHAT SHOULD THIS NEXT LINE BE TO IGNORE THE BASE PATH
    FROM THIS RULE TO SEND REQUESTS TO THE NODE APP? -->
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^$" negate="True"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: Spend some time on IIS.net's related pages. It shows so many examples and you should be able to learn how to use it instead of relying on others.

Comment: @LexLi If it was you who voted to close this question, could you help me understand why? I feel like I've asked a specific question about programming, which has a clearly defined answer. In what way is this "off topic" for stackoverflow? Thanks.

Comment: IIS configuration questions belong to ServerFault if you don't know before.

Comment: ~25k IIS questions on Stackoverflow would indicate otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iis

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add & modify the following rewrite content in `web.config` file:

```
<rule name="SpecificRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="/" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
</rule>
<!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
<rule name="DynamicContent">
    <match url="/api" />
     <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
</rule>
```

If the request matches the url `yourdomain`, it will rewrite the `index.html` in your root directory, and stop the rewirte process which present the `index.html` request be routed by node.js applicatio.

And also which configure the node.js application to handle the requesting in sub pattern `/api`.